# Update a collection with existing values in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a react web application with firebase and Now I'm stuck with this problem. So what I want is update the collection with existing data. For example let's say that the following details are already in the collection

```
org_details: {
   general: {
     org_name: "ane",
     founder: "fng"
   },
   group:{
     admin:{
       <details of the admin grp>
     },
     standard:{
       <grp details>
     }
   }
}
```

So what I want is add another group details with the existing groups. For an example I need to add a group called "fun" by also having admin and standard group. So this is the firebase query that I've tried.

```
export const createGroup = (data, history) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirestore }
) => {
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const { email: userEmail } = getState().firebase.auth;
  const groupName = data.groupName;
  dispatch({ type: actions.CREATE_GROUP_START });
  try {
    firestore
      .collection("org")
      .doc(userEmail)
      .update({
        "group": {
          groupName: {
            org_grp_admin: data.org_grp_admin,
            org_grp_users: data.org_grp_users
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        getOrgData(dispatch, getState, { getFirestore });
        history.push("/groupmanagement");
      });
    dispatch({ type: actions.PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: actions.CREATE_GROUP_FAILS, payload: err.message });
  }
};
```

But this query doesn't seem to behave like that I want. It always create a group called "groupName" instead of the group name that is passed from the parameter and always replace the existing data. How should I change the query to get the result that I want?

And I'm using firestore in firebase as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to dynamically assign the property key you need to wrap it in `[groupName]:{...}` to pick up the variable groupName instead of just the string `'groupName'`

```
"group": {
          [groupName]: {
            org_grp_admin: data.org_grp_admin,
            org_grp_users: data.org_grp_users
          }
}
```

As for performing a deep merge (e.g. just update the subgroup if it exists, and if not create the new group without deleting others), this is not possible with the current api however you could either

option 1) Read the data from the database first yourself and manually handle the merge before writing (you could either write your own function or use a package like [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge)

option 2) [Restructure your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data) to be flatter, for example using a subcollection to store your groups

Comment: Oh thanks for that. What would be the solution for the other problem?

Comment: What is the other problem? Have you implemented as above and receive a different error?

Comment: So what I need is to add another group for the existing group details. For an example there is admin and standarg groups already in the collection and I need to add another group called sample to that same list

Comment: Ok, I see... so sort of a 'sub-patch' or 'deep-patch'. I'm pretty sure this isn't supported by the native api methods, so 2 options would be either 1) read the document from the db and perform the patch yourself, or 2) restructure your data to be flatter, such as using subcollections. If that makes sense